# Add value to multiarray

Tags: php, arrays

```
<?php
$array = array(array(1,2,3), array(4,2,5), array(5,25,2));
foreach($array as $ar){
  $ar['test'] = 'test';
}
print_r($array);
```

http://codepad.org/FclkyyFa

Why this not working? I would like use foreach and add for each subarray test value.
how can i make it?

Comment: Your attempting to set the $ar value with the key `'test'` .. I don't see that array value?

Comment: $array['test'] = 'test';  [http://codepad.org/Oa8eoiBw

Comment: Use `foreach($array as &$ar){`. Otherwise you are adding `test` to a copy of the inner array which is discarded once outside the iteration.

Comment: @air4x why you can't add it as answer

Comment: There is an answer which explains it. You should select it.

Comment: I only added this to have at least a valid answer. Please add yours to get the credit - I'll delete mine afterwards. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The comment from @air4X is right. Use `&` to create a reference to the actual array and then set the value like:

```
foreach($array as &$ar) {
    // if you want to create an associative element called 'test'        
    $ar['test'] = 'test'; 
    // if you simply want to add the value 'test' to each array
    $ar[] = 'test';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to assign it with `array('test' => 'test')`.